# How can I respond to the selected item in a DropDownList using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html-select

I have a dropdownlist with several items in it. In anticipation of responding to the selection the user makes, I added the following "proof-of-concept" code:

```
$(document).on("change", '[id$=ddlPayToIndividual]', function () {
    var $individualSel = $('[id$="ddlPayToIndividual"]').val();
    if ($individualSel == "Damage Payment" {
        alert("you selected Damage Payment");
    }
});
```

But this not only doesn't work (I see no alert when selecting the "Damage Payment" selection), but prevents other, previously-working code from working. Is my assumption that the selected value can be accessed via "val()" wrong? Or...

Comment: can you just try $(this).val()?

Comment: Use your selector like this : $('#ddlPayToIndividual')

Comment: @crafter That will only bind to one ID, not all the IDs that end with `ddlPayToIndividual`

Comment: here's a working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/d7wowprj/

Comment: @Sushil, post your comment as an answer, please.

Comment: I can't use #ddlPayToIndividual because the generated ID is something like Champion9Sparky8Andersonvillage7Voice6of5reason4to3believe2you me1and0you~and!a@dog#named$Boo%Radl_ddlPayToIndividual

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `$(this).val()` to get the value of the selected dropdown. also if you need to use the id selector, just use `#ddlPayToIndividual`

but if you need to use this on several dropdowns, then as @Barmar suggested, try giving all your dropdowns a `class` and use the `class` selector instead of the `id`

here's what i have done.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(document).on("change", '#ddlPayToIndividual', function() {

        var value = $(this).val();

        if (value == 'Damage Payment') {
            alert('you selected Damage Payment');
        }
    });
});
```

notice the `#ddlPayToIndividual` instead of the `[id$=ddlPayToIndividual]` in the change event.

here's a working [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/d7wowprj/) for the same.

Comment: See my comment above on why I can't use a straight "ID is" syntax. It is rendered as select name="ctl00$ctl24$g_5f3fedca_19f7_4bc3_b84e_efbef0c48a33$ctl00$ddlPayToIndividual" id="ctl00_ctl24_g_5f3fedca_19f7_4bc3_b84e_efbef0c48a33_ctl00_ddlPayToIndividual">

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "add a class to it"

Comment: i mean css class meaning the element can be <select class='myDropDown' id='generatedID'></select>??

Comment: or you can use $(document).on("change", 'select', function() {

Answer (score 1):

To access the target element of the event, use `$(this).val()`. `$('[id$="ddlPayToIndividual"]').val()` returns the value of the first element in the document that matches the selector, not the one that triggered the event.

BTW, instead of using the ID selector `[id$=ddlPayToIndividual]`, you should give all these elements a common class, e.g. `class="ddlPayToIndividual"`. Then you can use the selector `.ddlPayToIndividual`.  E.g.

```
<select class="ddlPayToIndividual" name="ctl00$ctl24$g_5f3fedca_19f7_4bc3_b84e_efbef0c48a33$ctl00$ddlPayToIndividua‌​l" id="ctl00_ctl24_g_5f3fedca_19f7_4bc3_b84e_efbef0c48a33_ctl00_ddlPayToIndividual"‌​>
```

Comment: Do you mean each item in the "dropdownlist" should be assigned that class?

Comment: No, just the `<select>` itself.

Comment: Still not sure what you mean/how that is done, but my answer shows what I got to work.

Comment: Your way will work. I'm just suggesting a better, more efficient way to do it. I've updated the answer to show what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was getting "val" and the displayed value confused. As the dropdownlist/select is created like so:

```
DropDownList ddlPaymentToIndividual = new DropDownList();
ddlPaymentToIndividual.ID = "ddlPayToIndividual";
ddlPaymentToIndividual.Items.Add(new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem("Select type", "0"));
ddlPaymentToIndividual.Items.Add(new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem("Damage Payment", "1"));
. . .
```

...I had to change the jQuery to this:

```
$(document).on("change", '[id$=ddlPayToIndividual]', function () {
    var value = $(this).val();

    if (value == '1') {
        alert('you selected Damage Payment');
    }
    else {
        alert(value);
    }
});
```

Thanks to sushil's answer, I was able to see that.